# MQ sender- receiver channel issue

Tags: ibm-mq

I have two PCs both running Windows7 connected via LAN wire ( as homegroup network). In both PCs, I have installed MQ7.0. Let me name them: A and B
On A, I defined a queue manager QMA. On B, I created a queue manager QMB. Now I created a sender channel at system A: QMA.QMB and created a receiver channel at system B: QMA.QMB. This set up working fine. Both channel shows running. I have configured a sample remote queue defintion at system A and checked trace route message.

Now issue is reverse configuration. I want to create sender-receiver channel from B to A. So I followed similar steps to configured channel QMB.QMA. On system B, sender channel (QMB.QMA) keeps retrying. and at system A, receiver channel(QMA.QMB), it shows always inactive.
I have been trying couple of hours but no luck. Please help.

Pining ip address from both machines working fine. I am using tcp with default 1414 port. Listeners are up on both system. One strange thing, when I try display chstatus(QMB.QMA) on system A, it says "Channel status not found". and on system B,same command display channel status with status stopped. I have tried multiple times deleting-recreating channels. But no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to do is to see whether the connection request is even getting to QMA from QMB.  Check the `AMQERR01.LOG` file in `{WMQ Install Dir}/errors` and `{WMQ Install Dir}/QMgrs/QMA/errors` for indications of any failures.  If the connection request is getting to QMA but failing you should see it in the `QMA/errors/AMQERR01.LOG` file.  If it is getting to WMQ but not to QMA then you will find it in the WMQ global logs in `{WMQ Install Dir}/errors`.

If you *are* seeing the error in one of these logs, it should tell you what the problem is.  If there's a log entry and it doesn't resolve the issue, post the error log entry as an append to this question.

If you are *not* seeing it in one of these logs then look for configuration errors.  Make sure that the listener is running and on the port you think it should be.  Make sure the `CONNAME` points to the right IP address and port.  Make sure to use IP address and not the host name of QMA to take name resolution out of the equation.  Make sure that the Windows firewall is open for the port that is listening.  Go to QMB host and try top telnet to QMA host on the WMQ port.  If the connection is refused immediately or closes after a second or two then it is likely a firewall issue.

Comment: Thanks, logs helped. Basically I can see connection request is failing with following statement: Return code from TCP/IP call was 10065(X'2751'). Restarting one machine, it started working fine.